# Error when deploying Shopify React App with Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, shopify, create-react-app, shopify-app

I'm building a Shopify public app with a Firebase database. Everything works locally, but when I deploy it on Heroku, it doesn't authenticate, and the app displays an error.

[image]

The log is displaying an error message.

[image]

I'm following these tutorial https://medium.com/code-undefined/how-to-deploy-your-shopify-react-app-to-heroku-5dbc5a51738

Here is my server.js
https://github.com/amit-codeking/notification-bar/blob/master/server/server.js

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is looking for the `API_SECRET_KEY` config value to be defined, but it is not. This is causing the `params.API_SECRET_KEY.length` line to error, as it cannot call `.length` on `params.API_SECRET_KEY` due to it resolving as `undefined`.

You can follow the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to add this config value to your Heroku app. It seems as though the blog has it mislabeled as `SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY` so you may just need to rename that config value to match what your application is expecting. You may hit the same error with `SHOPIFY_API_KEY` just being `API_KEY` as well, so be on the look out.

```
heroku config:set API_SECRET_KEY whateverYourKeyIs
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct config vars are:

`SHOPIFY_API_KEY`

`SHOPIFY_API_SECRET`

I furthermore had to configure `HOST` and `SCOPES`.